# What's the point of using good/quality posts in First Post audits?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

When reviewing First Posts, I found no point to have a test review of an "already good post", since the answer of it is "No action needed".

All normal-to-good questions we just need to click the "No action needed" button. When I found this test, it looked like just another first-post, and after I clicked, it said "Congratulations!" but I feel like "So what???"

Anyone not paying attention is most likely to click "No Action Needed", so they will pass by luck, and doesn't identify if they were actually paying attention or not.
So I  thought that for this review category, isn't it better to just have only "bad posts" to put for test review?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good reviewers, like yourself, evaluate the post, and if deemed ok they click "No action needed", which means they're doing the job correctly, and so pass if it's an audit.
So in this case, for you, there is no issue - job done.

However I can see your concern.
Robo reviewers and users who don't pay attention or don't care will always just click "No action needed" quickly without reviewing first. Which means they will unfairly (luckily) pass an audit with a good post.

However, from what I can gather from reading Stack Staff replies, the audit and reviewing system is a bit more complex than giving people a free pass because they clicked "no action needed" in this scenario.

This sort of person is usually going to be clicking the same quick option every time (or most times), not downvoting, commenting, or flagging.
They are also likely to be doing this on other review queues, and such activity will likely (eventually) fire up a flag to someone  <sup><sub>(looking over your shoulder)</sub></sup>.

With a review suspension handed out if needed.

---

The review checking/audit system won't be perfect, it's impossible to check everyone perfectly, but it'll work for the most part, and won't just be as plain as your question makes out :)

Comment: Thanks, you really got my point, since my english is week I can't explain it well. however, you answer still not answered my completely, but anyway... it is just an opinion that I want it to be changed

Answer (score 6):

No. The intent of a review *audit* is to see whether you're paying attention. So, it includes both good and bad posts. Failing to identify bad posts, is bad. Failing to identify good posts, is just as bad.

Just cycling through reviews and clicking "No action needed" is not helping anyone. Then it's better to avoid reviews altogether.

Comment: I think the question is about what is the point based on it being a "test", just not very well worded.